# Vim no shortcut delay while still using shortcuts

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to use `<BS><BS>` to delete an entire word, however I do not like the small delay after pressing `<BS>` once to delete a single character. Is it possible to immediately display the single key press while undoing it and handling the shortcut properly when it is finished?